# Is it possible to reuse apmplify-js with token from another app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am building a web and mobile application and use AWS Cognito/amplify-js for managing auth.

Now we want to embed a part of web app inside mobile app and want to reuse the token already received in mobile application (without requiring the user to log in the embedded web part).

For now we didn't find a way to do it - looks like it's not possible to "rehydrate" a cognito session with just a JWT token.

Is there a way?

Comment: What do you mean by 'rehydrate'? Yes you can *reuse* but to *renew* it after its expiry, you need the refresh token.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, I mean the javascript amplify library does not accept the token from outside and handles session inside itself (for security reasons I guess). I want to use amplify-js with a token provided from outside.